# How to initialize INPUT in winapi in general?

Tags: c++, winapi

These two are definitions of [INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) and [KEYBDINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-keybdinput).

```
typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} INPUT, *PINPUT, *LPINPUT;
```

```
typedef struct tagKEYBDINPUT {
  WORD      wVk;
  WORD      wScan;
  DWORD     dwFlags;
  DWORD     time;
  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
} KEYBDINPUT, *PKEYBDINPUT, *LPKEYBDINPUT;
```

If I write below code(and it seems people usually use this or ZeroMemory or memset() which have same meaning),

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  INPUT input = { 0 };
}
```

all bits in the memory of `input` would be `0`. `0` is well defined for `type` in **INPUT** structure and `wVk` and `time` in **KEYBDINPUT** structure. But `wScan`, `dwFlags` and `dwExtraInfo` don't have explanation when its value is 0. Should I explicitly initialize these values rather than leaving it after `INPUT input = { 0 };`? That is, is it nonsense to initialize a value of an object which has no meaning for `0` to `0`?

Comment: dwFlags 0 means there's no flag set, dwExtraInfo means there's no extra info and wScan zero means scan code 0. In general you'd set at least wScan, for example using an API such as MapVirtualKey https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not **0**. The problem is that you need to initialize a **Controllable**, **Knowable** value. You can even use `memset(inputs, 1,sizeof(inputs));` which I tested.